# Planner is always in English

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-planner

I developed an .Net Core Application that creates a Group with a Team and a Planner asociated to it. By default, the language of the Group and Team is the one that I have configured in my local Team application (Spanish). But the Planner language is always in English and I dont find how to configure that using the GraphClient for C#.
If I create a Plan from my Local Team Application it is in Spanish, but if I created usingg the Graph API is created in English (everything else is in Spanish).

A few days ago I saw that there was a property in the Group object called preferredLanguage but seems that they have removed it.

This is the Plan created from the Graph API:
[image]

And this one is created from the Teams Application:

[image]

Just to clarify, i have everything in Spanish, including my O365.

Anyone knows how can I set the language of the planner to be spanish from the Graph API? Is this a bug?

Thanks a lot!

Luis

Comment: Can you explain the mechanism you are using to add a Planner tab to the Team? I believe it requires the Plan URL, are you passing in any locale code in the URL?

Comment: Hi Tarkan, thanks for your comment. I Am using the Microsoft.Graph nuget package for .Net Core. The urls I use are: https://tasks.office.com/macena.com.ar/Home/PlannerFrame?page=7&planId={planId} and https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/appCatalogs/teamsApps/com.microsoft.teamspace.tab.planner. No locales on them. I will take a look if i can add some locale in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to @tarkan-sevilmis that guided me in the right direction.

Accordint to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-configuring-builtin-tabs), you have to use the following urls:

**TeamsAppId**: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/appCatalogs/teamsApps/com.microsoft.teamspace.tab.planner

**ContentUrl**: https://tasks.office.com/{tenantName}/Home/PlannerFrame?page=7&planId={planId}

**RemoveUrl**: https://tasks.office.com/{tenantName}/Home/PlannerFrame?page=7&planId={planId}

**WebsiteUrl**: https://tasks.office.com/{tenantName}/Home/PlannerFrame?page=7&planId={planId}

But this created the Planner always in English. So I created a Planner manually using Teams for Windows (this one was created in Spanish) and I compare the two using [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) (GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{id}/channels/{id}/tabs?$expand=teamsApp)

I found out that the urls were a bit different:

**contentUrl** and **RemoveUrl** where https://tasks.office.com/{tenantName}/Home/PlannerFrame?page=7&planId={planId}&auth_pvr=Orgid&auth_upn={{upn}}&mkt={{locale}} (note here that I added &auth_pvr=Orgid&auth_upn={{upn}}&mkt={{locale}} at the end of the url).

**websiteUrl** was https://tasks.office.com/{tenantName}/Home/PlanViews/{planId}.

So I used these ones instead of the ones that the documentation said and Wuala! It worked.

*NOTE: in the URLs I just put in here I am using string interpolation (according c#), so take that in account when you read the URLs*

Comment: You should just need the "&mkt={{locale}}" piece. I'll follow up internally to streamline this.

Comment: Official Documentation of the configuration tab of Planner says not supported, yet we managed to write the configuration object for the Planner tab. I have done this for Planner while ago and it has been running smooth.. but my issue now is that I need tab for sharepoint list. Can we do the same magic for sharepoint list of the groups as a teams tab. Using Graph API